# fluentnhibernate and virtual entities

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, mapping

Why fluentnhibernate (v. 1.0) when you map the entities (not using automap), all must be virtual, even those that are not mapped? There is a way not to set props / methods virtual ?

Mic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a FluentNHibernate's requirement but rather NHibernate's. It is because when a property is marked as virtual features such as lazy loading are possible. There's a [blog post](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/03/must-everything-be-virtual-with-nhibernate/) describing the details behind this.